# iPhone browser adding right hand margin to some of the DIVs

Tags: iphone, css, html, safari, margin

This is how the site I'm putting together should look:
[GB Personal Training](http://www.gbpersonaltraining.com/)

This is what it looks like on the iPhone:
[iPhone Browser](http://i959.photobucket.com/albums/ae79/ianbarnard/photo.png)

As you can see it pushes in the #wrap and #outer-wrap DIVs, so that the background images in them have a right margin and I don't know why. I only have access to the custom.css file and not the HTML.

I'm currently editing a clone of it at:
gbptclone.live.subhub.com/

Answer (score 1):

Define `max-width` in your `body`. Write like this:

```
body {
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

add this inside your HTML`head`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but doesn't seem to change anything. Currently working on a clone of the site at: http://gbptclone.live.subhub.com/

Comment: I'll see if I can get the developer to add that in. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually this will prevent the user to zoom the content (wich sucks, from an user end experience):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Instead, in my opinion (and I am no guru), you should use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a width for #outer_wrap and #wrap (you probably want 100%).

It looks like Mobile Safari is expanding the size of the #visual-portal-wrapper div, which isn't enough because Safari resizes text for iPhone display. You can change this with -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; but that would make the links rather undersized for iPhone users. That's why it fits in a normal browser but not in Mobile Safari.

Changing the width of the divs should stop them from having content expand beyond their edges (they're 974px by default because that's what #visual-portal-wrapper is, but all the contents overflow and cause the visual errors) and have the background images appear cut off. You might also want to add background positioning for #outer_wrap since it appears slightly off on the screenshot from what I'm seeing in Firefox.

Edit: Alternatively, you could try changing the width: 974px; on the #visual-portal-wrapper div to min-width: 974px;, of course making sure you account for IE's problems with min-width).

Comment: Thanks. Though even when I use the  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;  it still has the space on the right hand side. Which specific DIVs do I need to add a width to, as there are quite a few in the content?

Comment: If I'm viewing this correctly, the #outer_wrap and #wrap divs don't have widths specified, presumably because the 974px of the #visual-portal-wrapper div is supposed to be enough to expand them to be wide enough to show their background images.

My guess is that they expand to the 974px correctly on Mobile  Safari, but then the #visual-portal-wrapper overflows because 974px isn't wide enough on that browser. Unfortunately, despite the overflow, the actual 974px width is already set in the CSS and cannot change, so the 2 wrapper divs don't widen properly.

Comment: It looks much better at 1000px wide for the #visual-portal-wrapper, just a small little space now.